# I'm confused about what to use to run Crystal Report in a client C# Winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I always have problem running some project in a client PC, I use Crystal Report in some form, those reports connect to a database located on a server (other PC).

In my master PC (where I do my programming), I install the following:

[CrystalReport Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFBue.png)

I have installed some CRruntime and `SqlClient` to the client PC; sometimes it works, other times is does NOT. To be clear, I don't know what I'm installing...

I just need to know what exact files I have to install in order to be able to run Crystal Report on a client PC.

I need to know, if in Visual Studio when I publish this file can be in the setup so it can be installed on the client PC?